# Compute the Hilbert-Samuel function

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, local-rings

Let $f\in R=k[x,y,z]_{(x,y,z)}$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, monic in $x$. Show that $(y,z)$ is an ideal of finite colength on $M=R/(f)$. Compute the corresponding Hilbert-Samuel function.

Maybe someone can do it as an example.